# Excel, Get count if two cells have specifice value

Tags: excel

i have an excel sheet with some test result(PPV Predictive Positive Value) like below, i want to find out the count if

[image]

Test1=1 Test2=1 count is 2
Test1=1 Test2=0 count is 1
Test1=0 Test2=1 count is 1
Test1=0 Test2=0 count is 1

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your table starts in A1 cell. Write this in C2 cell:

```
=MAX(A2+B2,1)
```

Or if you are a Boolean maniac:

```
=AND(A2;B2)+1
```

Then count the sum at the bottom of the column.

Comment: That is genius! I think you second option may have a regional/typo issue. This =AND(A2,B2)+1 or this =AND(A2:B2)+1 work for me, but I got an error with yours.

Answer (score 0):

If Test1 is in col A and Test2 is in col B, you could use a countifs formula like `=countifs(A:A,1,B:B,1)` for your first condition. Then, `=countifs(A:A,1,B:B,0)`, `=countifs(A:A,0,B:B,1)`, and `=countifs(A:A,0,B:B,0)` for your others.

The formula works by looking in col A for the condition you specify(1 or 0) and doing the same for col B, then only counting the ones that meet both criteria.